# Google Earth TimeStamp animation sequence issue

Tags: animation, timestamp, kml, google-earth

I have been trying to make a example of a animation in Google Earth (GE) by plotting points on the map at different times.  However I can't seem to get it to work.  I am using Google's KML and have looked at the documentation.

The following is a example of plotting 3 points at different timestamps. I am using the "TimeStamp" tag with the "begin" and "end" tags inside. This is how they show it working on the Google documentation page, however it does not seem to work becuase the time line on GE does not show up when I open the file (the timeline is always supposed to show up in GE when there are "TimeStamp" tags in the KML file).  However, when I change the "begin" and "end" tags to just a "when" tag, it seems to sort of work but not in the way I wanted to.  Does anyone know if I am using the "begin" and "end" tags wrong?  This is the doc that Google gives http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#timespan

Here is the example I was talking about. You can open it in GE by saving it as a KML file. You will see the 3 dots show up but no animation. What I really wanted to happen was have one dot show up, then disappear, then have the next dot show up and disappear ...

Thanks for the help in advanced everyone ;)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">

    <Document>

        <Style id="dotstyle">
            <IconStyle>
                <scale>0.3</scale>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://www.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~tnmeigs/images/dark-red-circle.png</href>
                </Icon>
            </IconStyle>
        </Style>

        <Placemark>
            <TimeStamp>
                <begin>2010-01-01</begin>
                <end>2010-01-02</end>
            </TimeStamp>
            <styleUrl>#dotstyle</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>110.43852082858155,-7.582042422936696</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>

        <Placemark>
            <TimeStamp>
                <begin>2010-01-02</begin>
                <end>2010-01-03</end>
            </TimeStamp>
            <styleUrl>#dotstyle</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>110.43852082858155,-7.592042422936696</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>

        <Placemark>
            <TimeStamp>
                <begin>2010-01-03</begin>
                <end>2010-01-04</end>
            </TimeStamp>
            <styleUrl>#dotstyle</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>110.43852082858155,-7.602042422936696</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>

    </Document>

</kml>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<TimeSpan>` rather than `<TimeStamp>` and it will work. `<TimeStamp>` expects `<when>` rather than `<begin>` and `<end>`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you look into using  `<gx:track>` It is used to move a placemark or model from one point to the next. More info here:
http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#gxtrack